# Sinatra and post datamapper association

Tags: ruby, rest, sinatra, datamapper, web-frameworks

I am building a rest api with sinatra and datamapper and I have my database file which looks like this:

```
require 'data_mapper'

DataMapper.setup(:default,'sqlite::memory:')


class Company
 include DataMapper::Resource

 property :id, Serial
 property:name, String, :required => true
 property:adress,String,:required => true
 property:city,String, :required => true
 property:country,String,:required => true
 property:email,String
 property:phoneNumber,Numeric
 has n, :owners, :constraint => :destroy

end

class Owner
 include DataMapper::Resource

 property :id,Serial
 property:name,String, :required => true
 property:id_company,Integer, :required =>true

 belongs_to:company
end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_migrate!
```

and I want to make a post method to add an owner to a company

```
post '/owners'do
  content_type :json
  owner = Owner.new params[:owner]
  if owner.save
    status 201
  else
    status 500
    json owner.errors.full_messages
  end
end
```

but when I tried to run this request I get this error :

```
curl -d "owner[name]=rrr & owner[id_company]=1" http://localhost:4567/owners
["Company must not be blank"]
```

Can somebody tell me how to make the association between the company and the owner in the post method?

Comment: "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it should not be id_company has to be company_id, changing...

```
 property:id_company,Integer, :required =>true
```

by

```
property :company_id,Integer, :required =>true
```

and doing curl on this way, has to fix this error

```
curl -d "owner[name]=rrr & owner[company_id]=1" http://localhost:4567/owners
```

Comment: Happy to heard that so you can check this answer as correct ;)

Comment: "[What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773/what-happens-if-you-answered-a-question-questioner-says-thanks-but-didnt-acce)"